# How bright was the AGN eruption at the center of the Milky Way ~2 Ma ago?

Tags: black-holes, history, observational-astronomy

The black hole at the center of the Milky Way is believed to have erupted as an active galactic nucleus (AGN) approximately 2 million years ago, at which time [it would have been visible to early humans](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn24257-early-humans-saw-black-hole-light-in-the-night-sky.html). How visibly bright would such an eruption have been, and how sudden would its onset have been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a footnote (5, p.9) to a paper describing the AGN eruption](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5455):

> While such an event would be spectacular to behold using modern
> astronomical techniques, to an ancient observer, escaping shafts of
> light that managed to pierce through the heavy dust obscuration
> towards Earth would have been at least an order of magnitude fainter
> than the full moon.

So with the moon being apparent magnitude -13, they are placing an upper limit of -10 on the apparent magnitude of the event.

Comment: I assume they're referring to apparent magnitude here. If so it would be good to add mention of that and note that (if I'm understanding, despite the tone of the quote) it would have been quite bright to terrestrial observers: brighter than any planet or even the "brightest historical" SN (SN 1006). Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: the statement would corresponded to "no brighter than magnitude -10", which is definitely brighter than any planet.  The 1965 comet Ikeya-Seki reached magnitude -10. (see http://www.icq.eps.harvard.edu/brightest.html).